# Tabs list issue

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im add this tab panel , i m add more list , only working 1st tab 2nd line is not working, what is the issue for this? please help me to fix this one issue,you can understand that issue click `tab 1` and `tab 02` not change 2nd `div`
Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
});
```

```css
/* USER PROFILE PAGE */
 .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(214, 224, 226, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card.hovercard {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.card.hovercard .card-background {
    height: 130px;
}
.card-background img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -ms-filter: blur(25px);
    filter: blur(25px);
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    min-width: 130%;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info .card-title {
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.card.hovercard .bottom {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.btn-pref .btn {
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">
        <div class="card-background">
            <img class="card-bkimg" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
            <!-- http://lorempixel.com/850/280/people/9/ -->
        </div>
        <div class="useravatar">
            <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
        </div>
        <div class="card-info"> <span class="card-title">Pamela Anderson</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

,

Comment: The problem lies in you using multiple IDs (`tab1`, `tab2`, `tab3`), which is invalid HTML. Please consider creating **classes** for these IDs instead :)

Comment: sir dis you mean, i remove the `#tab1` ` #tab2`  `#tab2`, after put the  classes `.tab1`

Comment: @ObsidianAge its working sir :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/y6zhs4h2/

```js
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
```

```css
/* USER PROFILE PAGE */
 .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(214, 224, 226, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card.hovercard {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.card.hovercard .card-background {
    height: 130px;
}
.card-background img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -ms-filter: blur(25px);
    filter: blur(25px);
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    min-width: 130%;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info .card-title {
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.card.hovercard .bottom {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.btn-pref .btn {
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">
        <div class="card-background">
            <img class="card-bkimg" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
            <!-- http://lorempixel.com/850/280/people/9/ -->
        </div>
        <div class="useravatar">
            <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
        </div>
        <div class="card-info"> <span class="card-title">Pamela Anderson</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href=".tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href=".tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href=".tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sir, Thank you ,

Comment: sir somthing wrong, i remove the ` <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>` after overwrite `tab2`  what happens this

Comment: @core114 Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/y6zhs4h2/1/

Answer (score 1):

Inside the href I changed like Obsidian aged said, the href to .tab1 .. 
On the tab contents I swapped the id to an class.

I prefer to have all the content in one tab-pane instead of having multiple but do it like you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".btn-pref .btn").click(function () {
    $(".btn-pref .btn").removeClass("btn-primary").addClass("btn-default");
    // $(".tab").addClass("active"); // instead of this do the below 
    $(this).removeClass("btn-default").addClass("btn-primary");   
});
});
```

```css
/* USER PROFILE PAGE */
 .card {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(214, 224, 226, 0.2);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;
    border-top-left-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;
    border-top-right-radius:5px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card.hovercard {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
.card.hovercard .card-background {
    height: 130px;
}
.card-background img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(25px);
    -moz-filter: blur(25px);
    -o-filter: blur(25px);
    -ms-filter: blur(25px);
    filter: blur(25px);
    margin-left: -100px;
    margin-top: -200px;
    min-width: 130%;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .useravatar img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 14px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info .card-title {
    padding:0 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
.card.hovercard .card-info {
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #737373;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.card.hovercard .bottom {
    padding: 0 20px;
    margin-bottom: 17px;
}
.btn-pref .btn {
    -webkit-border-radius:0 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6">
    <div class="card hovercard">
        <div class="card-background">
            <img class="card-bkimg" alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
            <!-- http://lorempixel.com/850/280/people/9/ -->
        </div>
        <div class="useravatar">
            <img alt="" src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/9/">
        </div>
        <div class="card-info"> <span class="card-title">Pamela Anderson</span>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-pref btn-group btn-group-justified btn-group-lg" role="group" aria-label="...">
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="stars" class="btn btn-primary" href=".tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Stars</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="favorites" class="btn btn-default" href=".tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Favorites</div>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group" role="group">
            <button type="button" id="following" class="btn btn-default" href=".tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <div class="hidden-xs">Following</div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>

        <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
            <div class="well">
      <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active tab1">
          <h3>This is tab 1</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab2">
          <h3>This is tab 2</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3">
          <h3>This is tab 3</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: sir somthing wrong, i remove the ` <div class="tab-pane fade in tab3"> <h3>This is tab 3</h3> </div>` after overwrite tab2 what happens this